# Chrome android 4.4 fullscreen or alternatives

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, webview

My problem is that i can't enable permanent fullscreen mode on my tablet with my site. Site uses html5 webcam API (getUserMedia) to deal with the camera. Android version of tablet - 4.4. I have tried to solve the issue by the running site in fullscreen android browser app, but all of it uses stock android webview and throws an error (Property 'getUserMedia' of object # is not a function) when i try to access the webcam. I can successfully run my site with all features in google chrome browser on this tablet. I tried to use fullscreen API but it wants user gesture to activate itself (this is really bad, but i will use it if there is no another solution)
Sorry for the mistakes, i hurry and english is not my native. Thanks for understanding!

Comment: I'm afraid your question is not very clear.  Not because of the English.  But because I can't tell what you're asking.

Comment: I've made kiosk-like html5 app that uses HTML5 webcam api (getUserMedia) for streaming and recording client video reviews.

Main requests:
1) Android 4.4
2) HTML5 webcam api
3) Fullscreen mode without user action (like button click etc)

I have tried to use http://www.android-kiosk.com/ and all is fine but it uses stock android 4.4 webview where getUserMedia is not supported.
I can use chrome for android, (it supports all needed features) but it needs user click for fullscreen mode. 
Still searching for the workaround

Comment: ok.  I see now.  There may not be a way to do this programatically.  This may require a special version of Chrome...  Or something.

Comment: Yes. I've spent hours of googling in searching of solution with no success.

Comment: The trouble is that you're trying to do something at a lower level than something out of the box (like Chrome) is going to provide.  You're trying to override something that's built in to the API.  Maybe you could request a custom build of Chrome that has that option...